# How to add an additional legend to hexbinplot in R using "key" or "legend"?

Tags: r, plot, legend

[Hexbinplot with  shaded region and dot-dashed line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FKKg.png)
I am creating a hexbin plot with added details using lattice::panel.xyz. I am trying to add a legend corresponding to the extra elements. I tried using the `key` option

```
library(hexbin)
library(scales)

set.seed(100)
ab1=runif(100)
set.seed(200)
ab2=runif(100)

hexbinplot(ab1~ab2,xbins=10
           ,panel = function(x,y) {
               panel.hexbinplot(x,y)
               lattice::panel.polygon(x=c(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0)
                                      ,y=c(0.3,0.5,0.5,0.3)
                                      ,col=alpha("skyblue",0.4), border=NA
               )
               lattice::panel.abline(v=0.5,col="pink",lty=4,cex=1.1,lwd=2.5)
           }
           ,key=list(text=c("dotted line","shaded region")
                     ,points=list(pch = c(NA,23), col = c(NA,"skyblue"), pt.bg = c(NA,"skyblue"))
                     ,lines=list(lty=c(NA,4),col=c("pink",NA),lwd=c(2.5,NA))
                     )
)
```

but I am getting an error: `Error in key[[i]][[1]] <- NULL : replacement has length zero`. Without the key attribute, I get a hexbinplot with a shaded region and a dotted line (attached). Required image would have a legendbox (maybe in the "topright" corner)

Any idea what has to be changed?

Comment: Shouldn’t you be looking at str output before trying low level assignments? I don’t see a documented `key` parameter on the help page.

Comment: @IRTFM, I'm sorry I don't quiet follow. Do you mean to use the str() instead of list()? Any idea what the _object_ might be?

Here's an excerpt from the hexbinplot() help page
>legend.width, legend 
width of the legend in inches when style is "nested.lattice" or "nested.centroids". The name legend.width is used to avoid conflict with the standard trellis argument legend. It is possible to specify additional legends using the legend or *key* arguments as long as they do not conflict with the hexbin legend (i.e., are not on the right).